# Printer scale in Swift

Tags: swift, printing

How can Swift code force the printer to print at a specific scale?

```
static func printImage(image: UIImage) {
    let info = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    info.outputType = .general
    info.jobName = "Printing"
    
    let vc = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    vc.printInfo = info
    vc.printingItem = image
    
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: image.size.height, height: image.size.width))
    vc.present(from: imageView.frame, in: imageView, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Neither `UIPrintInfo` nor `UIPrintInteractionController` has a scale operator.

Comment: Change the printer's paper size and its content inset